# Why git subtree pull overwrites top directory?

Tags: git-subtree

I added subtree using:

> git subtree add -P WLContainerControllers
>   https://github.com/an0/WLContainerControllers.git master

The resulting commit is:

```
commit bb77fe3c8244a42454b23285f174798116a5eaf8
Merge: 6686d73 755c342
Author: Ling Wang <xxx@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 25 17:20:29 2013 -0500

    Add 'WLContainerControllers/' from commit '755c342622fc6470e034f1b27e764329d7b8a01c'

    git-subtree-dir: WLContainerControllers
    git-subtree-mainline: 6686d73b438fc22514b36cdf76adf7ea9c35b558
    git-subtree-split: 755c342622fc6470e034f1b27e764329d7b8a01c
```

Then after some upstream updates, I did a subtree pull using:

> git subtree pull -P WLContainerControllers https://github.com/an0/WLContainerControllers.git master --squash

The output:

```
From https://github.com/an0/WLContainerControllers
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Removing WLPageViewController/main.m
Removing WLPageViewController/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
Removing WLPageViewController/damping.m
Removing WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController.m
Removing WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController.h
Removing WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController-Prefix.pch
Removing WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController-Info.plist
Removing WLPageViewController/PageViewController.xib
Removing WLPageViewController/PageViewController.m
Removing WLPageViewController/PageViewController.h
Removing WLPageViewController/ModelController.m
Removing WLPageViewController/ModelController.h
Removing WLPageViewController/Default@2x.png
Removing WLPageViewController/Default.png
Removing WLPageViewController/Default-568h@2x.png
Removing WLPageViewController/DataViewController.xib
Removing WLPageViewController/DataViewController.m
Removing WLPageViewController/DataViewController.h
Removing WLPageViewController/AppDelegate.m
Removing WLPageViewController/AppDelegate.h
Removing WLPageViewController.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/README.md
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/LICENSE
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/WLContainerControllers.xcscheme
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceState.xcuserstate
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.perspectivev3
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.pbxuser
Removing WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.mode1v3
Removing .gittrees
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .gittrees                                                                                                   |    4 -
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/AppDelegate.h => AppDelegate.h                                |    0
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/AppDelegate.m => AppDelegate.m                                |    0
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/Default-568h@2x.png => Default-568h@2x.png                    |  Bin
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLContainerController.h => WLContainerController.h            |    0
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLContainerController.m => WLContainerController.m            |    0
 .../WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers-Info.plist => WLContainerControllers-Info.plist           |    0
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.mode1v3                                         | 1403 ---------------------------------
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.pbxuser                                         |  542 -------------
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.perspectivev3                                   | 1530 ------------------------------------
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj                                     |  308 --------
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata        |    7 -
 .../project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceState.xcuserstate                               | 2264 ------------------------------------------------------
 .../WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/WLContainerControllers.xcscheme   |   76 --
 .../WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist          |   22 -
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/LICENSE                                                       |   27 -
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/README.md                                                     |    4 -
 .../WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers_Prefix.pch => WLContainerControllers_Prefix.pch           |    0
 .../WLContainerControllers/WLMultiContentContainerController.h => WLMultiContentContainerController.h       |    0
 .../WLContainerControllers/WLMultiContentContainerController.m => WLMultiContentContainerController.m       |    0
 WLPageViewController.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj                                                              |  372 ---------
 WLPageViewController/AppDelegate.h                                                                          |   15 -
 WLPageViewController/AppDelegate.m                                                                          |   52 --
 WLPageViewController/DataViewController.h                                                                   |   14 -
 WLPageViewController/DataViewController.m                                                                   |   37 -
 WLPageViewController/DataViewController.xib                                                                 |  236 ------
 WLPageViewController/Default-568h@2x.png                                                                    |  Bin 18594 -> 0 bytes
 WLPageViewController/Default.png                                                                            |  Bin 6540 -> 0 bytes
 WLPageViewController/Default@2x.png                                                                         |  Bin 16107 -> 0 bytes
 WLPageViewController/ModelController.h                                                                      |   17 -
 WLPageViewController/ModelController.m                                                                      |   89 ---
 WLPageViewController/PageViewController.h                                                                   |   16 -
 WLPageViewController/PageViewController.m                                                                   |   68 --
 WLPageViewController/PageViewController.xib                                                                 |  133 ----
 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController-Info.plist                                                        |   45 --
 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController-Prefix.pch                                                        |   29 -
 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController.h                                                                 |   48 --
 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController.m                                                                 | 1098 --------------------------
 WLPageViewController/damping.m                                                                              |   53 --
 WLPageViewController/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings                                                             |    2 -
 WLPageViewController/main.m                                                                                 |   18 -
 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/main.m => main.m                                              |    0
 42 files changed, 8529 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 .gittrees
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/AppDelegate.h => AppDelegate.h (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/AppDelegate.m => AppDelegate.m (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/Default-568h@2x.png => Default-568h@2x.png (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLContainerController.h => WLContainerController.h (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLContainerController.m => WLContainerController.m (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers-Info.plist => WLContainerControllers-Info.plist (100%)
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.mode1v3
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.pbxuser
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/an0.perspectivev3
 delete mode 100755 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceState.xcuserstate
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/WLContainerControllers.xcscheme
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/an0.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/LICENSE
 delete mode 100644 WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/README.md
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers_Prefix.pch => WLContainerControllers_Prefix.pch (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLMultiContentContainerController.h => WLMultiContentContainerController.h (100%)
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/WLMultiContentContainerController.m => WLMultiContentContainerController.m (100%)
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/AppDelegate.h
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/AppDelegate.m
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/DataViewController.h
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/DataViewController.m
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/DataViewController.xib
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/Default-568h@2x.png
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/Default.png
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/Default@2x.png
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/ModelController.h
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/ModelController.m
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/PageViewController.h
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/PageViewController.m
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/PageViewController.xib
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController-Info.plist
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController-Prefix.pch
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController.h
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/WLPageViewController.m
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/damping.m
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
 delete mode 100644 WLPageViewController/main.m
 rename WLContainerControllers/WLContainerControllers/main.m => main.m (100%)
```

It messed up the who directory.

The related logs are:

```
commit 0eaebf9a4842e53a19d0ffbddf1dadee69ef4e11
Merge: 3093049 1efe88d
Author: Ling Wang <xxx@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 25 18:02:27 2013 -0500

    Merge commit '1efe88dd79cb6fd550fceaaa10d4b22dc44fb9df'

commit 1efe88dd79cb6fd550fceaaa10d4b22dc44fb9df
Author: Ling Wang <xxx@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 25 18:02:27 2013 -0500

    Squashed 'WLContainerControllers/' changes from 755c342..2f2ca9a

    2f2ca9a Update project after moving LICENSE and README.md.
    d052945 Move LICENSE and README.md to top folder.

    git-subtree-dir: WLContainerControllers
    git-subtree-split: 2f2ca9ac87a7eebcac590ffba32577dc93c4963f
```

I'm using git 1.8.3.1 installed via homebrew on OS X 10.8.4.

What's wrong with my usage of git subtree? How to correctly use it? Thanks.

Comment: Could a commit higher upstream be messing with your subtree?

Comment: @IamJohnGalt How? However the upstream changes, it should only maps to  sub-directory `WLContainerControllers`, right?

Comment: That is true, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is due to some bugs of git-subtree. More specifically, after reviewing the complete logs after `git subtree add`, I found my commit history is messed up — there is no trace of commit logs of the super tree(the top directory). So I cleaned it up manually, and redid it using the lasted git checked out from github. Everything seems all right. I tried a `git subtree pull` after changing upstream and it works well too.

Is git-subtree still too cutting-edge to use in real projects?